# Application Identifier Prefix for iOS App? How to Discover/Obtain: or Not Required?

Tags: ios, swift, configuration, keychain, shared

I'm setting up a slightly out of the normal examples situation: I have a web service that acts as a tournament organizer for a game. The Game is in iOS, and if a player wants to play in a tournament, they need to provide their website credentials, which are used to connect to the service.

So, I want to have the app get the password for the site, and include it in a Basic Authentication request to the server. So to do that, I've gotten as far as having a apple authentication file available at the root of the service url, which right now is just this basic starting point:

```
{
  "applinks": {
      "details": [
           {
             "appIDs": [ "ABCDE12345.com.example.app", "ABCDE12345.com.example.app2" ],
             "components": []
           }
       ]
   },
   "webcredentials": {
      "apps": [ "ABCDE12345.com.example.app" ]
   },

    "appclips": {
        "apps": ["ABCED12345.com.example.MyApp.Clip"]
    }
}
```

I'd first like clarification: the part of this that will matter to me is web credentials, I assume? Which means that I can do without appclips and applinks?

Second, and more to the point, I've added an Associated Domain section to my Signing Capabilities, and it looks like

[image]

with my actual site name, with no subdomain preceding. Again, this is on the assumption that `webcredentials` is correct.... The answer I don't have is what the source of the prefix string that seems to be a generated identifier for the Bundle Identifier.

Mine is just a simple xxxx.myAppName; is that is all that's required in the apple associated app file above? Or, if not, where is that prefix sourced from. In case it matters, I'm using automatically managed signing on the app.

Comment: It is your team identifier; You can obtain it from your account at https://developer.apple.com

Comment: Thanks for the direction. In my App, there's a message to the effect that "Signing for "WordsBy2" requires a development team." Effectively, the id I get on the Apple Developer site fits that need, and it doesn't appear in the app because it's automatically managed, right?

Comment: You need to log in to your developer account in Xcode preferences. Then you can use automatic signing.  You need a paid account to use associated domains

Comment: For new apps created after June 2011, it is your Team Id. Otherwise you need to go to that app identifier in Apple Developer to find out. Read for more information https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2311/_index.html